# Email addresses show as [email protected] in TinyMCE textareas

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm writing a PHP script that pulls emails from a database and displays them in a TinyMCE textarea as a variable. The emails always show up as [email protected] when displayed in the TinyMCE textarea. How do I get the TinyMCE textarea to display the actual email?

Comment: Without a working example of your code and the content you are trying to load nobody will be able to answer this question.  Please see this page for details on what goes into a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you happen to rely on Cloudflare CDN for any of your JavaScript?

Comment: @Michael Fromin I do use Cloudflare for the domain. I'm not sure what CDN includes.

Comment: @Michael Fromin It works when I turn off Cloudflare. Care to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are seeing is a result of CloudFlare's Email Obfuscation:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-

If you turn this off you should stop getting this behavior.